# How many times Aditya Hridayam Stotra should be recited in one sitting?

Tags: stotra, surya, adityas

It is written in Walmiki Ramayana that Lord Rama recited Aditya Hridayam Stotra thrice before attacking Ravana in battlefield. 
The time domain was Tretayuga and Rama was a very pious human being.So, I personally think that it is the only reason that he got success by reading the Stotra thrice only.
Ordinary people like us might not get the full benefit just by reading it thrice.
So, how many times one should chant the Stotra? Please answer with proper explanation.

Comment: Aditya hrudayam is an interpolation in the Valmiki Ramayana. Does not occur in the Baroda critical edition.

Comment: Even I am also of the same opinion. It is not fitting into Valmiki's style.  Sri Rama was described as performing Sandhya rites daily. The Sandhya rites are dedicated to Savitr. Further, Sage Vishwamitra taught him Bala and Atibala.  Then what is the purpose of performing Aditya Hridayam?@Lazy Lubber

Comment: Unless you specify according to whom / what text, this question will unfortunately be closed by seeming primarily opinion-based

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of times a Mantra or Stotra is to be recited does not depend on who is reciting it. It depends on that particular Mantra or Stotra itself.

For example, for a Mantra, the number of times it should be recited to gain mastery (the Purascharana count) depends usually on the number of letters the Mantra is made of.

Also, it is said to depend on the age we live in. And, currently we are living in Kali.

One well-known instruction from the Tantras is that **the count must be quadrupled in Kali Yuga.**

> SankhyAsh-chaturguna-japah kalau ||
>
> The SankhyA or Japa count must be quadrupled in Kali Yuga.
>
> (This is quoted in [Brihat Tantra-SArah](http://www.shivashakti.com/tantrasara.htm))

But it appears that this injunction is not entirely Tantric in nature. Because the same rule is mentioned in the book ["Essence of Dharma Sindhu"](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookview.php?chapnum=24) too.

> Those who are always  engaged in Hari-Hara bhajana, Guru-Maata-Pita
>   Sev ana;and Go,Vishnu-Shiva Bhakta Seva are exempt fr om the blemishes
>   of Kali Yuga). **It is essential to  quadruple the prescribed number
>   of Japa and Puja in the context of Kali Yuga.** The fruits of virtuou
>   s deeds executed in ten years during Krita Yuga ar e equivalent to
>   what a person in TretaYuga would i n a year’s duration; or what ever
>   is earned in a month’s time in Dwapara Yuga; and what he or she w ould
>   earn in a day’s time and such is the magnitud e of good deeds in the
>   Kali Yuga! In fact, even th e very thoughts of doing good deeds would
>   fetch f ruitful results, let alone their actual performanc e.

So, if we assume 3 is the prescribed number, then in the context of Kali Yuga, it should be 12.