# Lakshmi ashtakam how many times a day and what other rules to follow?

Tags: mantras, lakshmi

The phalasruti of most of these astakams say something like -

```
Eka kaale pathen nityam ...
Dwi kaale pathen nityam ...
Tri kaale pathen nityam ...
etc.
```

But how many times each? and what other rules to follow?

Comment: The phalasruti portion of the Aditya Hridayam stotra states to recite it for 3 times from which it can be inferred that any Stotra/Kavacha/Ashtakam has to be recited  at least 3 times. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/36971/4732

Comment: Other rules include basic rules like one should recite with purity facing either East or North direction. Another thing peculiar to Stotra recital is that in this case recital should be loud (in case of Mantra chanting the best mode is the silent recital) https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33848/4732

Comment: @Rickross in the other post you mentioned that the count should be quadrupled in kali yuga, so is it going to be 3*4=12 times per recitation? and then 3 or 4 times a day depends on the phalasruti of the particular stotra?

And thanks for the tips on reciting loudly

Comment: I concluded that minimum number of recital should be 12 based on the rule that Puruscharana of mantras in Kali Yuga requires 4 times more chants. But for simple Stotra recital it might or might not be be true. So minimum chants could still be 3. Also Trikale refers to the 3 junctions of a day viz- sunrise, midday and sunset ..