Rules to chant Aditya Hridayam
What are the rules and restrictions to Chand Aditya hridyam stotra . Can we just chant it mentally in front of a burning Diya , and how many times should one chant in a day to get any fruitful result. Also what are the benefits one can get by chanting this stotra? Thank you.

Stotras should always be recited loudly there is no use in reciting them mentally .. Aditya Hridayam should be recited 3 times or may be 12 times now (In Kali Yuga). See - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36982/4732
